# Does Riemann integrability implies integral mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We know that if $f$ is continuous on [a,b] and $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, then there exists $c \in [a,b]$ with $f(c)(a-b) = \int_a^bf(x)dx$

If we change ''f is continuous on [a,b]'' to ''f is Riemann integrable'', does the mean value theorem for integral still holds? If not, Can you give me a counter-example?

I know that the first Mean-Value Theorem for Riemann-Stieltjes does not requires continuity, but that is still different from this statement.

reference:http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-first-mean-value-theorem-for-riemann-stieltjes-integrals

Comment: Suppose you have a function $f$ continuous on $[a, b] $ such that there is a unique $c$ satisfying the integral mean value theorem. Now change value of $f$ at $c$. By this you make $f$ discontinuous but still Riemann integrable and the mean value theorem does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $f(x) = x$ for $x \in [0,1]\setminus \{1/2\}$ and $f(1/2) = 1$?

Answer (score 2):

The counterexample served by mathcounterexamples.net is enough, but I will give the reason.

In the proof of the mean value theorem, you actually use the fact $f$ is continuous in a closed and bounded interval, precisely, you use the Intermediate Value property. Obviously, every Riemann integrable function need not satisfy the Intermediate Value property.

If you had mentioned $f$ is Riemann integrable and enjoys the Intermediate value property, then the mean value theorem holds, eg, the function $g(x)=f'(x)$ in a closed and bounded interval, $f$ differentiable on the interval. Then $g$ need not be continuous but is bounded and possesses the Intermediate Value property due to darboux's Theorem