# if $f$ is integrable in [a,b], $f$ domain's and $m\le f(x)\le M$ then exist $\beta\in[m,M]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx=(b-a)\beta$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f$ is integrable and $m\le f(x)\le M$ then exist $\beta\in[m,M]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx=(b-a)\beta$.

Is $f$ is continuous, by the intermediate values theorem, this $\beta$ is even the image of a $c$ by the function $f$, but what if $f$ is not even continuous ?

Comment: See this MSE post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780575/does-riemann-integrability-implies-integral-mean-value-theorem. Note also the linked proof.

Comment: What have you tried here? Continuity of $f$ is not the point.

Comment: For positive integrable function, $m\leq f\leq M\implies m(b-a)\leq \int_a^b f(x)dx\leq (b-a)M$.

Answer (score -1):

If a function f is integrable on the interval [a,b] and its domain is defined, and if there exist real numbers m and M such that m ≤ f(x) ≤ M for all x in the domain of f, then by the mean value theorem for integrals, there exists some number β in the interval [m,M] such that the definite integral of f from a to b is equal to the product of the length of the interval (b - a) and β.

Comment: The function might be discontinuous.